# How to deliver message to another actor if actor is not created in akka

Tags: akka

I am using actor to send messages to client over websocket. So each client when connected gets its own actor. Business logic simply does 
`actorSystem.actorSelection(s"/user/connections/UserQueues-${userId}") ! Message(content)`. 
For certain types of messages I need to persist a message if client is not connected and redeliver it when client connects. What is the best approach to route a message to the actor that will remember undelivered messages? This will happen if user has not connected yet and there is no actor with path s"/user/connections/UserQueues-${userId}" in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the websocket actor you could make it ACK getting this message, and if it didn't ACK you'd resend it again and again. Akka has built in support for this in akka-persistence's [AtLeastOnceDelivery](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.4/index.html#akka.persistence.AtLeastOnceDelivery), and here's how to use it [AtLeastOnceDelivery example in docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.7/scala/persistence.html#at-least-once-delivery).

Long story short, you need to switch from using `!` to `deliver(destination, deliveryId => Msg(deliveryId, s))` and then find a way to confirm that this message has been delivered (send a confirmation back to the sender and then call `confirmDelivery` inside it).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I don't think redelivery will work well in my case. Undelivered messages can be stored for days until client logs in.  Making resend timeouts too big is not an option because I need to show messages right after client logs in. Making it too small will put unnecessary burden on server. Effectively I need a nice way to intercept messages bound for dead letter queue because actor that represents my user is not instantiated yet. Storing / retrieving undelivered messages is a simple task.